# Hanoi sort algirithm

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

How to implement Hanoi sort in python? Rules of Hanoi sort: http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/hanoisort.html

My code:

```
def hanoy_sorted(arr, x, y):
    if len(arr) == 1:
        print(arr[0], x, y)
    elif len(arr) > 1:
        hanoy_sorted(arr[1:], x, 6 - x - y)
        print(arr[0], x, y)
        hanoy_sorted(arr[1:], 6 - x - y, y)


def merge(arr1, x, arr2, y):
    if len(arr2) == 0:
        hanoy(arr1, x, y)
    elif len(arr1) > 0:
        n = arr1[-1]
        j = len(arr2) - 1
        if n < arr2[-1]:
            print(arr1[-1], x, y)
            j = len(arr2)
        else:
            for i in range(0, len(arr2)):
                if n > arr2[i]:
                    j = i + 1
                    break
            hanoy_sorted(arr2[j - 1:], y, x)
            hanoy_sorted([n] + arr2[j - 1:], x, y)
            arr2.insert(j, n)
            merge(arr1[:len(arr1) - 1], x, sorted(arr2)[::-1], y)


def hanoy(arr, x, y):
    if len(arr) == 1:
        print(arr[0], x, y)
    if len(arr) > 1:
        mi = arr.index(max(arr))
        up = arr[mi + 1:]
        z.append(up[:])
        hanoy(z[-1], x, 6 - x - y)
        print(arr[mi], x, y)
        merge(arr[:mi], x, sorted(up)[::-1], 6 - x - y)
        arr.remove(arr[mi])
        hanoy_sorted(sorted(arr)[::-1], 6 - x - y, y)
        del z[-1]


n = int(input())
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))[::-1]
z = []
hanoy(arr, 1, 3)
```

There is an error in function merge: It sometimes puts bigger disk on smaller. How to fix that?

This programme prints what disk to move from rod1, to rod2.

Updated:
So I rewrote all my code and now I have that:

```
from sys import setrecursionlimit
setrecursionlimit(10000000)


def gen_moves(pos, prev_move):
    moves = []
    not_to_go = [prev_move[0], prev_move[2], prev_move[1]]
    not_to_go2 = [prev_move[0], prev_move[2], 6 - prev_move[2] - prev_move[1]]
    first, second, third = pos
    if first != []:
        if second != []:
            if second[-1] > first[-1]:
                moves.append([first[-1], 1, 2])
            else:
                moves.append([second[-1], 2, 1])
        else:
            moves.append([first[-1], 1, 2])
        if third != []:
            if third[-1] > first[-1]:
                moves.append([first[-1], 1, 3])
            else:
                moves.append([third[-1], 3, 1])
        else:
            moves.append([first[-1], 1, 3])
    else:
        if second != []:
            moves.append([second[-1], 2, 1])
        if third != []:
            moves.append([third[-1], 3, 1])
    if second != []:
        if third != []:
            if second[-1] > third[-1]:
                moves.append([third[-1], 3, 2])
            else:
                moves.append([second[-1], 2, 3])
        else:
            moves.append([second[-1], 2, 3])
    else:
        if third != []:
            moves.append([third[-1], 3, 2])
    if not_to_go in moves:
        moves.remove(not_to_go)
    if not_to_go2 in moves:
        moves.remove(not_to_go2)
    return moves


def do_move(arr, move):
    pos = arr[:]
    disk, from_rod, to_rod = move
    pos[from_rod - 1] = pos[from_rod - 1][:-1]
    pos[to_rod - 1] = pos[to_rod - 1] + [disk]
    return pos


def hanoi(arr, solved, prev_move):
    if not solved:
        moves = gen_moves(arr, prev_move)
        for move in moves:
            pos = arr[:]
            pos = do_move(pos, move)
            sorted_arr = sorted(arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2])[::-1]
            for i in range(3):
                if pos[i] == sorted_arr:
                    solved = True
            solved = solved or hanoi(pos, solved, move)
            if solved:
                moves_to_solve.append(move)
                break
    return solved


n = int(input())
arr = [list(map(int, input().split()))[::-1], [], []]
solved = False
moves_to_solve = []
sorted_arr = sorted(arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2])[::-1]
for i in range(3):
    if arr[i] == sorted_arr:
        solved = True
if n > 1 and not solved:
    solved = hanoi(arr, solved, [0, 0, 0])
moves_to_solve = moves_to_solve[::-1]
for move in moves_to_solve:
    print(*move)
```

It works right but if there are eleven disks programme prints segmentation fault. How to fix that?

Comment: 1. Find max disk on the rod.

Comment: 1. Find max disk on the rod. 2. Move recursivly all disks above max disk to the second rod. 3. Move max disk to third rod. 4. Merge first and second rod at the second rod. It sorts first and second rod. 5. Move sorted Hanoi tower to third rod

Comment: A comment on the article: Calling Hanoi Sort an optimum sorting algorithm is stretching things a bit. Many sorting algorithms have an O(1) best case. It just so happens that the worst case for most sorting algorithms is the best case for this particular sorting algorithm. And in practice, any sorting algorithm that has average case complexity of 2^n can hardly be considered "optimal".

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a recursive approach with a helper function to implement the tower of hanoi. Something like this;

```
def moveTower(height,fromPole, toPole, withPole):
    if height >= 1:
        moveTower(height-1,fromPole,withPole,toPole)
        moveDisk(fromPole,toPole)
        moveTower(height-1,withPole,toPole,fromPole)

def moveDisk(fp,tp):
    print("moving disk from",fp,"to",tp)
```

Comment: I don't think OP is trying to implement the tower of Hanoi. Instead, he seems to be interested in [Hanoi Sort](http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/hanoisort.html).

Comment: No. We have UNSORTED tower. We have to sort it on one rod. I have this code in fuction hanoi_sorted().